# React Router double slash after rendering the Link component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I just created a react app using create-react-app and this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
// import Navigation from "./components/navigation";

const Home = () => <div><h1>Home</h1></div>;
const Profile = () => <div><h1>Profile</h1></div>;
const Auth = () => <div><h1>Login</h1></div>;
const Navigation = () => (
  <div>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/auth">Login</Link>
    <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
  </div>
);
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But it renders the `a` tag get doubles slash and every time that I click on any link it put another slash on the URL.

[Updated]Here how its look like after I clicked a few times:

[image: Multiple slash with a few clicks.gif]

But if I instead clicking in the link type the exactly the right URL it works. How can I fix this? And why this is happing cause I just copy it from the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried to add to your <Link> element exact attribute?

Comment: I have checked your code and ran it many times it is working fine and even i am not getting that error you have mentioned. 
check this out:- https://codesandbox.io/s/x7r196vvwo

Comment: it works fine for  node v8.11.2 , npm v6.4.1,  react v16.6.3",
react-router-dom v4.3.1", can't reproduce the problem

Comment: I just updated the question with a gif on how its happening to me and I'm seeing the codesandbox and makes no sense to me. I'll try to create another project to see if gets the same problem.

Comment: I downloaded the Code Sand Box code and ran and it worked. Thanks @VikasSingh